# How to use the YAJL for objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, yajl

Hi can any one tell the steps to use the YAJL to parse the json object in objective c

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all described here: http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/

Answer (score 0):

Having just run through the process I put together a blog posting that fills in the gaps left by the very basic sample code shown on the main YAJL web site.

http://kevsaidwhat.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-yajl-with-objective-c.html